# Values not being saved into the array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

I am not used to JavaScript. I did some search, but still could not find out what's wrong with my code and I unfortunately don't have time to learn enough about it today.

I would like to store the data fetched from Firebase in the `course_data` array, but when I try to access it in the `.then(fs.append...` line, it comes out as `[]` and I know `doc.data()` was not empty.

```
fs.writeFile(filePath, "", (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The file has been initialized!');
    let course_data = [];
    coursesRef.get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            course_data.push(doc.data());
        })
    })
    .then(fs.appendFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(course_data), (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('success!!!');
        })
    )
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: return `course_data` in the first `.then`

Comment: Doing ```.then(querySnapshot => {querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            course_data.push(doc.data());
        })
       return course_data;
    })```
I still get ```[]``` as a result. :(
But thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `fs.appendFile` is executing immediately, and you're passing the result of the function into your promise, rather than the function itself. If you wrap that in an a simple arrow function I think it should work (Provided the function parameters are all in scope)

Comment: The argument to `then` must be a function to be invoked when the promise is resolved.  You're passing the result of `fs.appendFile...`, which doesn't make sense here.